# Getting calendar events using mailcore/mailcore2 or using libetpan

Tags: mailcore, mailcore2

is it possible to get the calendar events thorough IMAP client using libetpan?..I want to get the calendar events from mail server, so is that possible using libetpan/Mailcore? if posssible how can we do that?.

Comment: mailcore/mailcore2 are not meant to work with calendar.

Comment: What about syncing contacts from email account? Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot sync contacts with existing Mailcore or IMAP for that you need to have your own exchange server implementation then its possible

Comment: Hi Sandy, I am also looking for same requirement have you got any solution?

Comment: hi Minakshi, 

No i have not found solution.But only way out is to have your own custom implementation on server side which gives u the contact details from Exchange database.